# Merge two PCollection (Apache beam)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

I've two files in cloud storage.Contains of File1 in Avro format that has data from temperature sensor.

```
time_stamp     |  Temperature
1000           |  T1
2000           |  T2
3000           |  T3
4000           |  T3
5000           |  T4
6000           |  T5
```

Contains of File2 in Avro format that has data from wind sensor.

```
time_stamp     |  wind_speed
500            |  w1
1200           |  w2
1500           |  w3
2200           |  w4
2500           |  w5
3000           |  w6
```

I'want to combine output like below

```
time_stamp |Temperature|wind_speed
1000       |T1         |w1 (last earliest reading from wind sensor at 500)
2000       |T2         |w3 (last earliest reading from wind sensor at 1500)
3000       |T3         |w6 (wind sensor reading at 3000)
4000       |T3         |w6 (last earliest reading from wind sensor at 3000)
5000       |T4         |w6 (last earliest reading from wind sensor at 3000)
6000       |T5         |w6(last earliest reading from wind sensor at 3000)
```

I am looking for the solution in apache beam to combine above file. Right now it is reading from file but in future it may come via pubsub. I want to find out custom way of combining two PCollection and create another PCollection tempDataWithWindSpeed.

```
     PCollection<Temperature> tempData = p.apply(AvroIO
         .read(AvroAutoGenClass.class)
         .from("gs://my_bucket/path/to/temp-sensor-data.avro")

     PCollection<WindSpeed> windData = p.apply(AvroIO
         .read(AvroAutoGenClass.class)
         .from("gs://my_bucket/path/to/wind-sensor-data.avro")

     PCollection<WindSpeed> tempDataWithWindSpeed = ?
```

Comment: There is several solutions. Can you add more detail? For example, is the temperature timestamp is as regular as displayed in the example? Is stream processing or always batch processing? Do you perform many extra transform after the merge in your pipeline? What kind of transform?

Comment: Here is a good example, how to join them: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/pipelines/design-your-pipeline/#multiple-sources

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere How does transform affect the solution. Right now it is batch processing.

Comment: @jszule I saw that example and join key used is name of user. I don't have join key directly, I need some custom solution to join.

Comment: Still you can go with join the sources, just you have to create a KV values like `KV<Long, WindData>` and `KV<Long, TempeData>`, where the key is the timestamp bin in both cases where the timestamp belongs to (Eg: 2200 belongs to key 2000, so you have to round down to thousands). Once you have created the groups, you can select the min or max or whatever you need sensor value. Hope this helps :)

Comment: The batch process lead me to recommend you big query. An outer join and some analytics functions should solve the issue. You pay only the data read, 4 small column-> very cheap. This query can be the entry point of your pipeline, but, if the transforms are simple enough, you can achieve this with SQL function or UDF. Sorry for asking and looking for better solution.

Comment: To help with 'validity windows' you can look into the State and Timers APIs. I recommend this [blog post](https://beam.apache.org/blog/2019/06/11/looping-timers.html) and [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y_HoNNU6b3I) about the topic.

Comment: How often do your sensors emit data? Is it a fixed frequency? You may be able to use some sort of sliding windows for this

Comment: In order to combine two PCollections, you would have to create a Key so you can perform a [CoGroupByKey](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#requirements-for-writing-user-code-for-beam-transforms). Although, in case you can not come up with a Key-value as Primary keys for joining the PCollections, you can upload these two PCollections to BigQuery (as already mentioned by @guillaumeblaquiere )and work with your data there because it will be easier to manipulate it. Would that work for you?

Answer (score 2):

The comment by @jszule is a good answer in general for Dataflow/Beam: The best supported join is when the two PCollections have a common key. For most data Beam can figure out a schema and you can use [`CoGroup.join`](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.23.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/schemas/transforms/CoGroup.html#join-org.apache.beam.sdk.schemas.transforms.CoGroup.By-) transform. The design decision you have to make is how to choose the keys, such as rounding down to the nearest 1000.

Your use case has a complication: you need to carry forward values in a time series for keys that have no data. The solution is to use state and timers to generate the "missing" values. You will still need to carefully choose keys since state and timers are per-key-and-window. State and timers also work in batch mode so this is a batch/streaming unified solution.

You may want to read [this blog post by Reza Rokni and myself](https://beam.apache.org/blog/looping-timers/) on the subject, or [this talk by Reza at the Beam Summit Berlin 2019](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y_HoNNU6b3I)